# How can Typescript correctly infer generics in react component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Just for context, I'm creating a component that shows a Tooltip if the child element is overflowing. `children` prop is a render function so whoever calls this component can assign the `RefObject` to whichever ref prop of the child component it wants (i.e.: ref, itemRef, inputRef,..), as well as the event that should be called `onMouseEnter`.

```js
import { TooltipProps } from '@mui/material';

export type OverflowTooltipProps = Omit<TooltipProps, 'children'> & {
    children: <RefElem extends HTMLElement>(
        ref: RefObject<RefElem>,
        onMouseEnter: () => void
    ) => ReactElement;
};

const OverflowTooltip = <RefElem extends HTMLElement>(props: OverflowTooltipProps) => {
    const { children, disableHoverListener, ...other } = props;
    const [overflowing, setOverflowing] = useState(false);
    const childrenRef = useRef<RefElem>(null);

    const testIfOverflowing = () => {
        const scrollWidth = childrenRef.current?.scrollWidth;
        const clientWidth = childrenRef.current?.clientWidth;
        if (scrollWidth && clientWidth) {
            setOverflowing(scrollWidth > clientWidth);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        testIfOverflowing();
        window.addEventListener('resize', testIfOverflowing);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', testIfOverflowing);
    }, [children]);

    return (
        <Tooltip disableHoverListener={disableHoverListener || !overflowing} {...other}>
            {children<RefElem>(childrenRef, testIfOverflowing)}
        </Tooltip>
    );
};
```

This is a (simplified) use case:

```js
<OverflowTooltip title={attachment.file.name}>
    {(ref, onMouseEnter) => (
        <Chip ref={ref} label={attachment.file.name} onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} />
    )}
</OverflowTooltip>
```

However, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't this be inferred correctly because of the generics being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to pass generic into to type also. Here you have working solution:

```
import { Chip, Tooltip, TooltipProps } from "@mui/material";
import { ReactElement, RefObject, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export type OverflowTooltipProps<RefElem extends HTMLElement> = Omit<
  TooltipProps,
  "children"
> & {
  children: (ref: RefObject<RefElem>, onMouseEnter: () => void) => ReactElement;
};

const OverflowTooltip = <RefElem extends HTMLElement>(
  props: OverflowTooltipProps<RefElem>
) => {
  const { children, disableHoverListener, ...other } = props;
  const [overflowing, setOverflowing] = useState(false);
  const childrenRef = useRef<RefElem>(null);

  const testIfOverflowing = () => {
    const scrollWidth = childrenRef.current?.scrollWidth;
    const clientWidth = childrenRef.current?.clientWidth;
    if (scrollWidth && clientWidth) {
      setOverflowing(scrollWidth > clientWidth);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    testIfOverflowing();
    window.addEventListener("resize", testIfOverflowing);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", testIfOverflowing);
  }, [children]);

  return (
    <Tooltip
      disableHoverListener={disableHoverListener || !overflowing}
      {...other}
    >
      {children(childrenRef, testIfOverflowing)}
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

const attachment = {
  file: {
    name: "test",
  },
};

const App = () => {
  <OverflowTooltip<HTMLDivElement> title={attachment.file.name}>
    {(ref, onMouseEnter) => (
      <Chip
        ref={ref}
        label={attachment.file.name}
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      />
    )}
  </OverflowTooltip>;
};
```

Comment: That works, however, isn't there a way to make the typescript compiler infer that type correctly without having the user explicitly specify the generic type?

Comment: Oh Yes, you're right I overlooked that I put that here. Give me a second; maybe I can figure something out

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible because the result of a function

`const children = (ref, onMouse) => (<Chip ref={ref} label={"example"} onMouseEnter />)
`
gets inferred as JSX.Element, not anything specific. If you do something like this:
`const children = (ref: any, onMouseEnter: any) => (
  <Chip ref={ref} label={attachment.file.name} onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} />
);

type Return = ReturnType<typeof children>;`
You will see what I mean

Comment: I see, perhaps in the future React/Typescript can make that simpler to infer. With that said, your solution does work tho, so I'm marking it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, and sorry that TS hasn't lived up to your expectations. There are things I feel should just work but don't. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, TS is excellent, much prefer it over standard JS. But yeah, I agree with you, can't be frustrating. With every update it gets better, let's hope this kind of inference is possible in the future